# How do I reduce the bundle size of React Leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, leaflet, gatsby, react-leaflet

I have a Gatsby.js project where the parsed size of my bundle is 3.92 MB. **1.1 MB** of that is `leaflet-src.js`. Leaflet also seems to supply `leaflet.js` which is only 508 KB. After reading [this issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5288#issuecomment-279397985), whenever I import Leaflet, I always import this smaller version, like so:

```js
import L from "leaflet/dist/leaflet"
```

Regardless, whenever I run Webpack Bundle Analyzer, both `leaflet-src.js` and `leaflet.js` are imported:
[Webpack Bundle Analyzer Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4UO5.png)

It seems like the GitHub issue I mentioned was hinting at configuring webpack to use the optimized version, but I'm really struggling to figure out how to do that exactly.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this may be an issue of how react-leaflet is importing leaflet.  While any direct references from your code to leaflet may use the `import L from "leaflet/dist/leaflet"` option, react-leaflet source and build code simply imports from 'leaflet', with the assumption that you have leaflet as a peer dependency.  So that means react-leaflet is bringing in the unminified version, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/402).

As react-leaflet author LeCam states, you've got to manage this yourself.  You'll have to find a way to tell webpack to replace all references to the 'leaflet' module with directions to the 'leaflet/dist/leaflet' file.  You can start by looking at the [redirect an import](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2558) issue with webpack, or the [NormalModuleReplacement plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/).

Also, this should help in your own code, as you can just `import L from 'leaflet'`, and if you've setup your webpack correctly, it will redirect to the minified version.

Comment: I really like the plugin you've recommended. I've implemented it with no luck like this:

          new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
            /leaflet\/dist\/leaflet-src\.js$/,
            "leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"
          ),

Comment: I've never personally used that plugin, so I can't help you there.  One way or another, you've got to get webpack to forward all references to leaflet to the leaflet/dist/leaflet.js.  If you're having trouble with that, it probably deserves its own question.

Comment: That's fair. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I just realized I've been putting my config in the wrong folder. It works flawlessly now! Thanks again!